# Ckeditor issue with InsertText

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to use the following command to insert a text to the CKEditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.Body.insertText('$${FIRSTNAME}');
```

The above command works fine when the cursor is at plain text. When i try to insert the text between a text which has  attribute, it inserts on single $ instead of $$ of $${FIRSTNAME}. I have uploaded the sample to the jsbin to reproduce the issue

http://jsbin.com/ahikeh/1

Please suggest an alternative to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly bug :D I debugged the code and find the reason:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/editable.js#L1616

`String#replace` method treats `$$` as one `$` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), so the data should have been protected.

I'm afraid that there's no simple workaround right now since you cannot escape the data beforehand. Depending on context the `replace` method will or won't be used.

So the best option will be to use other template pattern - e.g. `%%{foo}` - it will work correctly. And when getting data from the editor you can replace `%%` with `$$`.

Ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10367

Comment: Thanks for the update. We'll try to use a different symbol rather than $, until this issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [insertHtml()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml) instead:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.Body.insertHtml('<b>$${FIRSTNAME}</b>');
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/ikirup/2/)**

Comment: Its working fine with insertHtml, but i have an another concern. I need to insert that value based on the text in the CKEditor, If I insert it between a strong tag, it should look like bold and if I insert it in plain text, it should look like that. The inserted text should have the similar style of the text where the cursor is currently located.

Comment: if the cursur is within a span with a style or a bold tag.. The inserted html would be the same style.. The only reason it could break is because of block level elements within inline elements. Which is not correct within html.